# Shift running X window (display environment) on SSH X11 forwarding

Tags: xorg, ssh, display, remote, x11-forwarding

I want to see remotely some running GUI application without kill the current process, I have tried vnc and xrdp, xrdp opens a new blank session, so it is not for me, vnc is good, but not exactly what I need, it uses the screen and devices presents, someone could mess with me moving the mouse or typing on the keyboard.

Therefore I figured out the only way I could do what I need is managing to shift a running X window from one display to another, thus even on a SSH -X (X11 forwarding) I would be able to see it.

I am on this quest for a long time and I didn't found out a conclusive solution, that is the reason I am appealing to you. Could you help me to solve this trouble?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you folks, but another friend found a [better answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20706739/shift-running-x-window-display-environment-on-ssh-x11-forwarding), I want to share with the world for someone with the same problem:

There is some tools such as [xmove](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xmove) and [Xpra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xpra) that works as a X proxy, allowing you to retain the window opened in a kind of virtual X Server, and catch the window to your environment when you need, exactly what I need!

Thanks dudes.

Comment: Nobody knows about `nx`?!

Answer (score 0):

VNC is basically the only way to get what you want. You cannot change the active `DISPLAY` of a running program in X11. You'd have to close the current program and run it again on the new `DISPLAY`. There are also many other services which may be in use by currently running programs, which also require the same `DISPLAY` and which require other environment settings, which are not present when you use `ssh -X` to connect to a remote machine.

Answer (score -1):

(If I understand your question correctly) Try looking into tmux or screen as possible answers here. Put one of these on the system in question, start it then inside it run the application.

You can "detach" from tmux, then re-attach from another system and access the application.

Comment: `tmux` and `screen` are only for terminal applications.